# Как получить ID3 в правильной кодировке?

Tags: java, android

Использую MediaMetadataRetriever для получение тегов, но русские теги иногда в ISO-8859-1, что при переводе в Windows-1251 должны читаться, однако у меня такого не происходит и выводит все время иероглифы

Строка в файле такая: ß õî÷ó áûòü ñ òîáîé

Должно быть: Я хочу быть с тобой

```
String TEXT = META.extractMetadata( MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE );
new String( TEXT.getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "Windows-1251" ); // Практически всегда выводит иероглифы
```

Нашел библиотеку и решил использовать ее для проверки

```
mp3file = new MP3File( FILE );
new String( mp3file.getID3v1Tag().getSongTitle().getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "Windows-1251" ) // Выводит текст как надо, но иногда вместо кириллических символов проскальзывают латинские
```

Подскажите, как определять кодировку и декодировать в читаемый вид. Я думаю наверняка есть нативный способ